# Количество уникальныз значений

Tags: mysql

Прошу помощи. 
Нужно сделать выборку и в разрезе дня выдать сумму уникальны значений сначала по одному полю, потом по второму.

Группировки подходят только для даты. 
Получается сумма всех повторяющихся значений, а нужно только уникальных `channel` и `src`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(calldate, 1, 10), COUNT(channel), COUNT(src), ROUND(SUM(billsec)/60, 0), ROUND(SUM(duration)/60, 0) FROM $userstable WHERE (channel LIKE '%SIP/iFree%') AND (SUBSTRING(calldate, 1, 10) BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-30') AND (disposition LIKE 'ANSWERED') GROUP BY SUBSTRING(calldate, 1, 10) DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуйся `distinct`.